# How to pass Class Type in method parameter in java

Tags: java

```
public <T> void doSomething(List<T> businessList) {
  for(T bank : businessList) {
    String name = bank.getName();
  }
}
```

I am getting the error below when calling `getName()` :

> Cannot resolve method getName()

Comment: bind `T` to some type having the method `public String getName()`.

Comment: Why don't you use an interface instead of `T` ?

Comment: LIst<T> can be List<Bank>, List<School> etc.

Comment: To explain @turing85's comment, you need `List<? extends HasName>` and `interface HasName { public String getName(); }`.